# Tool for impacting screws — What is it called?

Tags: tools, stuck-bolt

What is the name of this tool?

Purpose: Hit it with a hammer to loosen a seized screw, etc.

[image]

Source:

- YouTube channel "wtbm123": [Can your screw driver do this, Weird Tools and my ratcheting screwdriver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpXBuC0kCeg&t=33s)
- Go to 0:33. Speed up the playback speed since this guy talks slowly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's (to my knowledge) called a [screw impact driver](https://www.google.com/search?q=screw+impact+driver), impact screwdriver,  hand impact screwdriver, or just impact driver.

Comment: Another name I came across: [*Manual* Impact Driver](https://www.princessauto.com/en/9-pc-manual-impact-driver-set/product/PA0008840191).

Comment: @User1974 - Well, we know how you Canadians are about things :P (Haha, assuming that from Princess Auto, lol :o) Nonetheless, thanks for the add!

Comment: Interestingly, I was sniffing around for a very small tool like this a few weeks ago: I ended up having to drill out a Pz-headed screw deep in a precision mechanism which had been secured with Blue Loctite and was wondering whether impact would have broken the seal.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - It may have. Blue Locktite isn't supposed to be super strong and a good shock from something like this will usually break it free. If the availability is there, heat works the best for freeing a stuck Locktite fastener. Red is usually a lot more problematic.

Comment: IIUC, red Locktite is supposed to _require_ heat to break the bond. (I've been wrong about other things, though, and could be wrong about this too...)

Comment: @FreeMan - You are right about red. However, to get blue to break free easier, you can use heat on it as well. You're just trying to break the bond, which heat works very well.

Comment: Actually, just hitting a rusty screw with a hammer (and nail punch) is sometimes sufficient to loosen the screw.

Comment: I call it a manual impact driver, and it's a very handy tool to have to loosen small fasteners that have seized or someone has messed up by using the wrong size screwdriver.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It was a "moving head" lamp, and I had to get in very deep to replace the LED. As a ballpark figure it must have taken me a couple of hours stripping it and 30 putting it back together, this time using a bit of Purple which is just about the weakest.